# i want to sort the list of objects based on the attribute of that object without considering the special characters

Tags: python

```
  Item1=Item("The Book of Mormon","Joseph smith Jr.",1992 ) 
   Item2=Item("Charlettes web","E.B.White",2013) 
   Item3=Item("The prince of tides","PatConroy",2004) 
   Item4=Item("Arise! Awake!","Josephine",1992) 
   Item5=Item("Wonder","R. J.Palacio",2008) 
   item_list=[Item1,Item2,Item3,Item4,Item5]
```

I want to sort the list "item_list" based on the author names. but while sorting i should ignore the special characters. Then the final output should be a list contaning Item2,Item4,Item1,Item3,Item5

Comment: Please give us an example of the expected output. Also what is the definition of Item? What do you mean by special characters?

Comment: Item is a class. item1, item2, item3 etc are the objects of Item class. item_list is a list of objects. i want to sort that list "item_list" based on the attribute "author" which is defined in Item class. the problem is sorting them without considering the special characters like ".", ",","-" etc

Comment: for the question mentioned above if I give inputs as Item1=Item("The Book of Mormon","Joseph smith Jr.",1992 )
Ietm2=Item("Charlettes web","E.B.White",2013)
Item3=Item("The prince of tides","PatConroy",2004)
Item4=Item("Arise! Awake!","Josephine",1992)
Item5=Item("Wonder","R. J.Palacio",2008)
new_item_list=[Item1,Ietm2,Item3,Item4,Item5] Then  the final output should be [item2,Item4,Item1,Item3,Item5]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to create a list containing only the letters (so no special characters are considered) and sort based on that as follows:

```
import re

class Item:
    def __init__(self,item_name,author_name,published_year):
        self.__item_name=item_name
        self.__author_name=author_name
        self.__published_year=published_year

    def get_item_name(self):
        return self.__item_name

    def get_author_name(self):
        return self.__author_name

    def get_published_year(self):
        return self.__published_year

Item1 = Item("The Book of Mormon", "Joseph smith Jr.", 1992) 
Ietm2 = Item("Charlettes web", "E.B.White", 2013)
Item3 = Item("The prince of tides", "PatConroy", 2004)
Item4 = Item("Arise! Awake!", "Josephine", 1992) 
Item5 = Item("Wonder", "R. J.Palacio", 2008) 

item_list = [Item1, Ietm2, Item3, Item4, Item5] 
new_item_list = sorted(item_list, key=lambda x: re.findall('\w', x.get_author_name()))

# For each class item in the new list, display its values
for item in new_item_list:
    print "{}, {}, {}".format(item.get_item_name(), item.get_author_name(), item.get_published_year())
```

This would give you:

```
Charlettes web, E.B.White, 2013
Arise! Awake!, Josephine, 1992
The Book of Mormon, Joseph smith Jr., 1992
The prince of tides, PatConroy, 2004
Wonder, R. J.Palacio, 2008
```

The `re.findall('\w'), x)` regular expression returns a list of just the characters contained in the author's name, thus removing all of the special characters. So for example the first item would be sorted using a sort key of:

```
['A', 'n', 'd', 'r', 'e', 'w', 'W', 'h', 'i', 't', 'e', 'h', 'e', 'a', 'd']
```

Comment: but i want to sort the entire list of objects based on the Authors (which is a second parameter of Item class) without consedering the special characters

Comment: why remove white spaces?

Comment: Thanks Martin Evans

Comment: @EricDuminil, it is mainly to show the OP an approach, obviously it can be adapted as required, for example it could also be made case insensitive.